# Can we make a static method in a single class to move Intent multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have more than 50+ activities in a single project so each and every time I need to write code to move a single activity from one to other.

What is in my mind, may I make a single function which can move more than one activity from a single static method of a class?

Like given in code below.

```
public static void moveActivity(Parameters)
{
//Code to move activity
}
```

Or may I follow any other idea for the same.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What is in my mind, may I make a single function which can move more than one activity from a single static method of a class?

I believe not because `startActivity` needs a `Context` which can't be used in a `static` context, I believe.

> Or may I follow any other idea for the same.

This depends on what you are doing but maybe [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and/or [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) could make your life easier. If you have that many `Activities` then most likely you won't want to try and manage them all from one function anyway because you have to consider `extras`, `flags`, etc... You will have two lines to start an `Activity` (sometimes more) just write the code. What you are trying to do will most likely result in more headaches, IMHO.

If there is a lot of the same data that you are passing around and that is your concern then you can use [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass them all around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Utils {

    public static void launchActivity(
            Class<? extends Activity> nextActivityClass,
            Activity currentActivity, Map<String, Integer> extrasMap) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, nextActivityClass);
        if (extrasMap != null && extrasMap.size() > 0) {
            Set<String> keys = extrasMap.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                launchIntent.putExtra(key, extrasMap.get(key));
            }
        }
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        currentActivity.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }

}
```

To use it:

From your activity class, make this call:

```
Utils.launchActivity(ActivityB.class, this, extrasMap);
```